# What's the best practice for having 4 loops over same data in an MVC 4 view?

Tags: asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view that contains 4 columns (HTML Divs). Each contains a different subset of the same data, based on my Place model (I'm just outputting the name property, there is also a category property - both strings).

I could create a ViewModel, containing 4 place models, each with the appropriate data in.

I could pass 4 strings with markup in (probably not good as mixing markup with data?).

What would be the best practice here?

(I also need to output the places in alphabetical order, by category - outputting a heading when the category changes - though this is a secondary requirement).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use the first option, a ViewModel containing 4 `PlaceViewModel`s. It will provide you with the flexibility of manipulating the objects and their properties, and display them as you want; and it will also improve maintenance of the view in the long run,

```
@model PlacesViewModel

@foreach (var place in Model.Places)
{
    // Render your HTML column here 
}
```

By passing a set of HTML strings (as mention in the second option) you won't be able to modify, inspect, parse, iterate or manipulate your objects in any useful way. You would be left to manipulate the strings using some sort of client-side framework, like jQuery.

However, if you simply want to iterate over a set of `PlaceViewModel`, you think about passing a list of them, and in your `View` do something like,

```
@model List<PlaceViewModel>

@foreach (var place in Model)
{
    // Render your HTML column here
}
```

which will save the need of having an extra class.

To order the models alphabetically by name (or any other property), do,

```
@foreach (var place in Model.Places.OrderBy(place => place.Name))
{
    // Render your HTML column here 
}
```

Comment: nice thanks.

would it be bad practice to just pass some strings of HTML in? That would offer a lot of flexibility (but does feel wrong I must admit).

Comment: @user2254951 Updated my answer to explain my take on it.

Comment: all the lists are is HTML links to another page - so once passed in would have no idea for further manipulation. But just passing HTML from controller to View - would that be considered bad practice?

Comment: Well, not necessarily. I thought you were passing complex HTML structures back to the View. If they are just a list of URLs or links, you can use `List<string>` or `List<MvcHtmlString>`. It really depends on how complex the `PlaceViewModel` structure is.